# what is 'this' is javascript

Tags: javascript, this

Can I ask what mean 'this' in javascript, any resources on 'this', and what mean this.submit in a form?

Comment: Surely you mean any resources on 'this'?

Comment: Did you investigate this question *at all* before posting?

Comment: `this.submit()` in the context of a form would submit the form... It makes sense, if you think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes, there are resources on `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: mozilla have a lot of javascript tutorial?Can you give me a link where is the mozilla javascript tutorial collection?

Answer (score 2):

Source: Google - I'm feeling lucky

http://justin.harmonize.fm/index.php/2009/09/an-introduction-to-javascripts-this/

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the current object.  so if I have something like:

```
var someVar = {
  some: 'thing',
  another: function(){
    return "thing";
  },
  more: function(){
    this.some + this.another();
  }
}
```

Then the `this` in those statements refers to `someVar`, so you're calling the function `another()` that is a member of `someVar` ...

Answer (score 0):

`this` is the *self* reference to an object.

Used within an object, `this` refers to that object itself.

Used outside (not within an object) `this` refers to the *global* object.

Thus

```
  function Func(z) { this.x = z; }
```

and running

```
  Func(7);
```

will set the *global* variable *x* to 7.

While doing

```
  var o = new Func(3);
  var p = new Func(4);
```

will create two objects, *o* and *p*, and set the *property* of the Func instantiation *x* to 3 for *o* and to 4 for *p*.

A well designed explanation is on [this site](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/).

Answer (score 0):

The text in the PDF bellow explains "this" - and how it changes - in depth.

https://github.com/spencertipping/js-in-ten-minutes/blob/master/js-in-ten-minutes.pdf

(Sorry, it is not directly acessible on the web, you have to download the stuff)